# Changing an Image view based on input in Android Studio: Converting a string input to an acceptable png title

Tags: java, android-studio, mobile-application

How do I change an Image view based on input?
My code gets the title of the png as a string and passees it into the getter function but that does not work. Is there anyway to convert the string input into an acceptable png title?

For reference:
[here is my AS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ14a.png)
and the image file in my raw folder is
[titled the same as the string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTb1V.png)

I expected this to get the png title that matched what the string states but understand that this was never the case due to the lack of quotation marks. So what can i do?